# Javascript library to connect to facebook chat

Tags: javascript, titanium, xmpp

I am trying to create a mobile version of a facebook chat client. I am using Titanium appcelerator to do the job so I write Javascript code.

I need a working library that is not DOM dependent (there is no DOM on mobile devices) or uses it in a minor way that will allow me to quickly change it.

it should also be as small as possible. I will take care of the GUI but I need the communications and protocol part.

Also, do I need any other components to connect to facebook XMPP servers ? BOSH or something like that ? why is it needed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strophe.js might be what you're looking for.

> Strophe.js is a pure-JavaScript library. The implementations are production ready, well documented, easy to use, and easy to extend.

http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/

> Strophe provides the following features:
>
> - XMPP compliant (Strophe.js compatibility matrix libstrophe compatibility matrix)
> - Browser and platform agnostic (Strophe.js)
> - TLS support via SChannel, GNUTLS, or OpenSSL (libstrophe)
> - SASL authentication using ANONYMOUS, DIGEST-MD5, or PLAIN methods as well as legacy jabber authentication
> - Customizable logging and memory management

Comment: is this library for real ? I have been trying to download it for the past few days and get a broken link:http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/strophejs/releases/strophejs-1.0.1.zip

Comment: Since I can't see it and check if it is small and maintainable, are there any other options ?

Comment: I did, I got it and found core.js, this is a big library.

Comment: does anyone know of anything more lightweight ? and can someone explain why and if I need BOSH ?

Comment: if you find something more lightweight please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Moshe,

I have written some instructions here: https://github.com/javierfigueroa/turedsocial
I hope this helps people trying to get FB chat going using strophe.js

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

u need bosh to convert the stateful xmpp sessions to stateless http sessions                chat client<->xmpp<->BOSH<->http<->facebook....                                                This would giv u a better idea- http://metajack.im/2008/09/08/which-bosh-server-do-you-need/

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically for Facebook and uses `node-xmpp`: https://github.com/Takeno/node-facebookchat